# Look for keywords and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a working code that does exactly what I want it to do, loops through a particular part of an excel document looking for certain keywords, then pasting those keywords into a separate sheet in the excel spreadsheet. It is just very long and doesn't allow for any more than 20 repetitions. I was wondering if anyone had advice on making this code loop until the user selects vbNo when asked if they have any more keywords?

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastLine As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
s = 2

For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then

        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1

If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
If MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next
s = s + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, glad you chose to post it here! I edited the title to say what the code does (which is the norm here). I hope you get some great reviews!

Comment: To be clear about our scope, we can help you clean up what you've done, but implementing new features is outside of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Instead of hard coding x number of searches, add a loop (I used a `While...Wend`) that repeats until the user enters a blank search term. This will allow them to search for as few or as many words as they need to on this run.
- Instead of looping through all the cells of the worksheet, using the `.Find()` method will be much, much faster. There are a couple of caveats

  - `.Find()` uses the current `Find` settings exactly as they are in the find dialog box, so you'll want to set as many of the parameters as are important to you. I've set a minimum in the code sample - you may need more
  - `.Find()` will continue looping through your workbook with no warning that it's returned to the top, so you need to store off the address of your first found item & compare it each time through.

Something like this:

```
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastLine As Long
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range

Dim findWhat As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rng as Range
Dim Address as string

s = 2
findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
While Len(FindWhat)> 0  'loop until they enter a blank search string
  j = 1
  rng = ActiveSheet.Find(What:=findWhat, LookIn:=xlValues)
  if not rng is Nothing and rng.address <> address then 'if we found something & it's not the first cell we found
    if len(address) = 0 then 'if this is our first find
      address = rng.address  'store the cell address so we don't loop forever
    end if
    rng.copy destination:=Sheets(s).Rows(j)
    j = j+1
    rng = ActiveSheet.Find(What:=findWhat, LookIn:=xlValues)
  end if

  s = s + 1

  MsgBox j - 1 & " results were copied"
  findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What other word would you like to search for today?"))
Wend
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, FreeMan. Here, we like a little bit more context in our reviews. This could be a really great answer, but as it stands is little more than a code dump. Add some more context to your answer to illustrate what your code does and why you choose to do it in that way.

Comment: The only bug I see is what happens when the user performs more searches than there are sheets. (I'm assuming that previously there were enough sheets)

Comment: It's pretty simple, @Snowbody, the code crashes and throws an error! :) Yeah, there should be some logic in there to add in a new sheet if one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

@FreeMan did a great job at *loopifying* your <kbd>Copy</kbd>+<kbd>Paste</kbd> code; I just have a few more [important] points to add:

> ```
> Option Compare Text
> ```

Great, so you know about module options. One that you should always systematically add to **every** VBA code module you ever write code in, is `Option Explicit`: that option will prevent the code from running (compiling actually) if you're using a variable that you haven't declared anywhere.

As it turns out, variable `s` isn't declared, so `Option Explicit` would break your code until you add a declaration for it.

The easiest way to ensure `Option Explicit` is always on, is to have it enforced by the VBA Editor itself - check the "require variable declaration" box in the Tools/Options menu:

[image: "require variable declaration" checkbox in the "Editor" options]

Another way is to install the [**Rubberduck**](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) VBE add-in (disclaimer: I wrote it with [@RubberDuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/rubberduck)), and to run code inspections:

[image: Rubberduck code inspections]

As you can see the static code analysis tool is picking up another issue in your code: the `Macro2` procedure is *implicitly public*. This would fix it:

> ```
> Public Sub Macro2()
> ```

What's the difference? Well, did you know that unless a `Private` access modifier is specified, all procedures (and functions) in a code module are public by default? Not a big deal really, but readability-wise, being explicit about these things helps tremendously - especially if you're coming from [pretty much any] another language, where members are all *private* unless specified otherwise.

---

## Meaningful Names

One of the hardest thing in programming, you'll find, is *naming things* (well, [that and cache invalidation, apparently](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)). A procedure called `Macro2` only means, to me (to *future you* as well), that there's possibly another procedure somewhere called `Macro1`... maybe.

A good way to make it easier to name things, is to write small procedures that do as little as possible - when procedures do only one thing, naming them after what they do becomes pretty simple. Procedures *do something*, so their names should start with a verb.

Single-letter identifiers are also meaningless. `s` surely means something... but nobody knows *what* until they scanned all its usages and inferred its meaning - a name like `destinationSheetIndex` would bring sunshine to the life of whoever is maintaining that code.

---

## DANGER!

This line is dangerous:

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

It has the power to make your user believe Excel has frozen when, in reality, it's just idle and happily waiting for `SceenUpdating` to be turned back on.

You should only use it in procedures where you're properly handling any possible runtime error that might happen - by *Murphy's Law* there will always be a way for something that *can* go wrong, to go wrong.

Here's a procedure template I use all the time:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'method body goes here

CleanExit:
    'cleanup code goes here
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    'error-handling code goes here
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

So, if the method body needs to turn `ScreenUpdating` off, you can avoid confusing users by simply specifying `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` under the `CleanExit` subroutine, so that whatever happens, screen updating is restored before the procedure exits. I wouldn't rely on Excel to automatically clean up for me.

Comment: Good call with the screen updating.  VBA is so cumbersome without Try...Finally blocks.

Comment: I like the variation. "There are two hard things in C.S., cache invalidation, naming things, and off by one errors."

Comment: I did leave `Application.screenUpdating=False` commented out... :)